Regex stop at space & skip rest of the info in a line
I am working with some data that the last portion of sometimes has additional information than others. When this additional information exists, I need regex to skip it and move on to the next line.
So sometimes my data ends like this:
LAT:35.7427280 LONG:-86.1315921 GRIDREF:01800S 01600E
Other times it ends like this:
LAT:35.7427280 LONG:-86.1315921
(There is a lot more before that, but I have removed it for simplicity)
In the below code, sometimes "GRIDREF" exists and I just need it to ignore that and move on to the next line. Sometimes it does not exist, in which case I need it to move on to the next line. Either way, after LONG ends, I just need it to move on to the next line and ignore everything after LONG.
$re = [regex]'(?si)TYPN:(?<type>.*?)\sLAT:(?<lat>.*?)\sLONG:(?<long>.*?)\s*(?:GRIDREF:.*?\s*)
Currently if GRIDREF does not exist, then it makes "long" the entire next line, until it comes to "GRIDREF". I have tried removing "GRIDREF" - but so far, that causes that data (if it exists) to be included in "long"
I have tried $re = [regex]'(?si)TYPN:(?<type>.*?)\sLAT:(?<lat>.*?)\sLONG:(?<long>\S*?) hoping that would just ignore anything once it comes to the space after LONG:, but it gets stuck with that.

Please make a [mre]. This isn't a valid Python regex; I get re.error: unknown extension ?<l at position 7 on Python 3.12 and 3.8. It looks like those are supposed to be named groups, which use ?P.

Also, there's no \s before LAT in this data. It seems like you forgot to remove that when reducing your full code.

Oh wait, is this just a typo? \S*? should be \S*

the leading \s is just a copypasta mistake

That's not Python... is it Powershell?

You are correct, I am using both Powershell and Python for what I am working on and got my streams crossed, sorry about that.

"There is a lot more before that, but I have removed it for ....." making the question not a [mre]

Might not be relevant, but I'd use split instead to pull out the lat and long.
If x = "LAT:35.7427280 LONG:-86.1315921 GRIDREF:01800S 01600E" or
x = "LAT:35.7427280 LONG:-86.1315921" then
x.split(" ")[0:2] returns ['LAT:35.7427280', 'LONG:-86.1315921'] which you can then rebuild into a string or process in whatever way you want.


You regex specifically matches for TYPN but that part is not in your example.
It also does not show how the string is generated.
This makes it NOT a Minimal Reproducible Exmaple and thus makes much harder to offer good help.
For example, your code tries to match a multi-line string.
It's possible that there is a simple way to instead generate a array of strings thus removing the problem at the root.
Please UPDATE YOUR POST.

Because of point 1 I'm going to be forced to assume(and you know what that makes out of both of us).


$Pattern = '(?si)TYPN\:(?<type>[^\s]+)[^LAT]+LAT\:(?<lat>[^\s]+)[^LONG]LONG\:(?<long>[^\s]+)'
example
$Pattern = '(?si)TYPN\:(?<type>[^\s]+)[^LAT]+LAT\:(?<lat>[^\s]+)[^LONG]LONG\:(?<long>[^\s]+)'

# Yes, it's cheeky to use your own post text, if modified, as example.   
# More reason to give better context.    
$Text = @'

I am working with some data that the last portion of sometimes has additional information than others. When this additional information exists, I need regex to skip it and move on to the next line.

So sometimes my data ends like this:

sfepiwsh cvwnspiehs TYPN:1649498 
LAT:35.7427280 LONG:-86.1315921 GRIDREF:01800S 01600E

Other times it ends like this:

aòdi TYPN:hpnachdxpa LAT:35.7427280 LONG:-86.1315921


sfsdf
sfepiwsh cvwnspiehs TYPN:1649498 LAT:35.7427280 LONG:
-86.1315921 GRIDREF:01800S 01600E


'@

$Result=[regex]::Matches($text,$pattern)

# You can access the values with $Result[index of the match].Groups['Name of the capturing group'].Value
$Result[0].Groups['lat'].Value


I downvoted for the martyr preachy stuff; if there isn't enough info for an answer then comment to ask for more; if you're going to answer with some assumptions then do that. But it's Q&A not Q&chastising&lecturing&A.

I didn't mean being preachy, only sassy, but I see how it might be taken as such... not getting the "martyr" part tho'.
